# Remote command completion for ssh host foo<TAB>

Tags: shell, ssh

Are there any shells that have `ssh host 'partial command<TAB>'` do remote completion (i.e. by sshing to the remote machine, running completion there for the partial command, and displaying the results locally)?

Comment: Wondering without fist login to host how remote completion can work..

Comment: @Bharat connection reuse (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410252/how-to-reuse-an-ssh-connection) or ssh-agent w/ ssh-add

Comment: assuming fish on the remote (& local) machine, remote completion for salt (https://github.com/saltstack/salt/commit/8e19313fa996a7e5f09230761459a50e7a36cb73#diff-0d5993169a3a7cd507d917168871b4e6R334) should be adoptable to ssh